# Proving negative natural log of Beta($\alpha$, 1) distribution is an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm looking to prove that taking the negative natural logarithm of a Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta=1$ is an exponential functions.  I've found two different proofs, both of which use a transformation formula.  However, that is not something I've learned yet.  Is there another way to show this?

Answer (score 3):

Let $X \sim $ Beta$(\alpha,1)$, $Y := \ln X$. Then 
$$
  P[Y \leq y]
= P[X \leq e^y]
= \frac{B(e^y;\alpha,1)}{B(\alpha,1)}
= \alpha B(e^y;\alpha,1), \quad y \leq 0,
$$
since $B(\alpha,1) = \alpha^{-1}$. Here $B(e^y;\alpha,1)$ is the [incomplete Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function):
$$
  B(e^y;\alpha,1)
= \int_0^{e^y} t^{\alpha - 1} dt
= \frac{1}{\alpha} \left. t^\alpha \right|^{t=e^y}_0
= \frac{1}{\alpha} e^{\alpha y}.
$$
Putting this all together you get 
$$
  P[Y \leq y]
= e^{\alpha y}, \quad y \leq 0.
$$